# Average of Averages in Excel

Tags: excel

What's the best way to get the total average over time of averages?

```
85% 87% 89% 95%       89%
78% 90% 85% 98%       88%
78% 85% 95% 87%       86%
74% 83% 92% 87%       84%
```

The column on the far right are the averages of each individual row, but I'm looking to get the average of the far right column. I have a feeling this needs to be a weighted average, but can't figure out how to plug the arrays correctly using AVERAGE.WEIGHTED in Sheets without returning an error. Or is there a better way to achieve the overall average of the far right column?

Comment: Why does it need to be a weighted average? Weighted averages are for where one value in the average is more significant than others, and needs to have more influence on the overall answer. To Weight the average you'll need to put a 'weight' next to each value to show how important it is. If they're all equally important, just use a normal average.

Comment: `=AVERAGE(far-right-column)`

Comment: Is this really as simple as a straight average of...all of the averages? My brain is going back to middle school where I'm thinking averaging averages isn't supposed to be done.

Correct me if I'm wrong: the only time you can truly average an average is if all variables are the same weight and if the number of entries are the same.